# Ethernet cable CAT 7 installation

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, rj-45

I'm installing an ethernet network on my house. One of the cable goes under the floor so this installation is meant to stay like this for a while. So I try to buy the most recent hardware for future compatibility.

I bought a category 7 ethernet cable. After that, I tried to find wall plugs that are compatible with cat 7. However I didn't find any.

I'm therefore wondering if I can plug my cat 7 cable on a cat 6a RJ45 plug. Because it's the most I can find currently.

I know that most of current hardwares don't support cat 7 ethernet but I want a sustainable solution.

The path would be as follow:

```
ROUTER_1 ---6a_CABLE--- RJ45_6a_WALL-PLUG ---7_CABLE--- RJ45_6a_WALL-PLUG ---6a_CABLE--- ROUTER_2
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Usually changing the wall sockets is much easier than changing the cable between them. Therefore if in future you really want to make use of CAT7 you can still change the wall sockets and re-use the cable. At the moment CAT6a is sufficient for 10-Gigabit-Ethernet...

Comment: Okay but do CAT 6a wall sockets are compatible with CAT 7 cable ?

Comment: If you are able to, put a conduit under the floor (best practice anyway) and then use CAT6e cable. This is vastly easier and CAT 5e still works and is near 3 decades old. So imagine easy upgradability .

Comment: CAT7 cable just supports a higher frequency compared to CAT6a, therefore every CAT7 cable supports CAT6 and older. The only difference is that CAT7 cables have usually a bit larger (diameter). Therefore make sure the used wall sockets are prepared for the size of the cable.

Comment: OK so for the time being the only "matter" I will have is that I will get cat 6a performances? Which is fine for me anyway.

Comment: Are you wiring this for 1Gbps or 10Gbps?

Comment: @PaulBénéteau - If you plug a CAT7 into a CAT6a wall socket that is wired to a switch that is connect by CAT7 you would get CAT7 performance.  The differences between CAT6a are due to the wire shielding contain within the cable.  (*Since the wall socket itself contains wires, if those wires are not properly shield to allow the higher frequency, you would indeed get CAT6a performance.*)  CAT7 and CAT6a both support RJ45 connectors.